# Git commits not in any branch, what happened?

Tags: git

We were missing a feature in master that we developed a while ago. After a bit of search, we found some commits for that feature. Now if we run

```
git branch --contains xyz
```

it outputs nothing.

I guess somehow we accidentally removed the branch that were containing these commits. But is there some way to know what happened?

Comment: Somebody checkout a tag and developed that feature on top of it?

Comment: Could the OP somehow have been working with a "detached HEAD", and not converted to a branch that would be committed?

Answer (score 0):

Nothing gets deleted on git (unless the garbage collector goes through), everything can be recovered so if it was there will still there.

If you have gitk installed run this command and search for your missing branch:

```
gitk --all `git reflog | cut -c1-7`
```

Or just `git reflog` and search for the lost change.

Once found take note of the hash and check it out.

Comment: `git` does have [garbage collection](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-gc.html) which could delete loose objects (objects not reachable by any branch or tag) once in a while. Of course you can configure whether or not it should be used automatically, and how long objects should remain before they can get deleted.

Comment: Is there a way without gitk?

Comment: just use "git reflog" to navigate the history and search for the lost change, is not that confortable as with the GUI of gitk but will work. Will update the answer.